# Problem storing characters as an string inside a while loop

Tags: c++

I'm having problems with this simple example.

The program inquires as to how many letters are required to form a complete word. Then it will ask for each letter individually, which is fine, but I can't make the code save the value from the current character and the next one from the next iteration until the number of letters finishes the word and print it to confirm the word.

E.g. Let's say house, which has 5 letters.

```
int numbersOfCharacters=5;
int counter=0;
char character;
string phrase;

while (counter < numbersOfCharacters)
{
    cout << "Introduce character's number" << counter << ": ";
    cin >> character;
    counter = counter + 1;
    phrase=character+character; //I'm not sure if I need an array here.
}

cout << "Concatenated characters: " << phrase << endl;
```

The output is:

```
Introduce the character number 1: h
Introduce the character number 2: o
Introduce the character number 3: u
Introduce the character number 4: s
Introduce the character number 5: e
Concatenated characters: ?
```

**And the expected output should be**:

```
Concatenated characters: house
```

**Update**

Using John's comments I was able to resolve the issue. It's not a lack of debugging information but instead know the proper operator for this solution. Thanks also to Remy Lebeau for the detailed info.

Comment: Replace `phrase=character+character;` with `phrase+=character;` Not sure what you think your version is doing, but if you want to append a character to a string variable use `+=`.

Comment: My advice is to obtain a debugger. If you had a debugger you could have stepped through the code line by line looking at the variables and flow and seen the output of `phrase` after `phrase=character+character;` which should have showed you that this was clearly not what you want to do.

Comment: yes! that makes the trick! thanks @john

Comment: John's answer fix my issue, it was not a debug problem i think but instead how to properly add the characters at the end of the current variable value. I've tried with append also but didn't work. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user2965052, you can also use push_back method available in the string class `phrase.push_back(character);` https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/

Comment: @DarkSorrow cplusplus.com is (IMHO) a very poor resource to reference. It has lots of incomplete and incorrect information. I'd recommend using https://en.cppreference.com/w/ instead, as a much better reference site.

Comment: I don't miss any debugging information, it's a matter of comprehend the operators.. I need some clarification that's all. I don't know why this has a -3.. Sometimes you just don't see a solution. If we cannot ask for help on stack .. haha then should be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `phrase=character+character;` doesn't do what you think it does. You are taking the user's input, *adding its numeric value to itself*, and then *assigning* (not appending) that numeric result as a `char` to the string.

So, for example, on the 1st  iteration, the letter `h` has an ASCII value of 104, which you double to 208, which is outside the ASCII range. On the next iteration, the letter `o` is ASCII 111 which you double to 222, which is also outside of ASCII. And so on. That is why the final string is not `house` like you are expecting.

Perhaps you meant to use `phrase=phrase+character;` instead? But, that won't work either, because you can't concatenate a `char` value directly to a `string` object using `operator+`.

What you can do is use `string::operator+=` instead:

`phrase += character;`

Or the `string::push_back()` method:

`phrase.push_back(character);`

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. It was not a lack of debugging but actually find the operator to add more characters to the string. This matches with John's solution.